# SQL group per class and rate

Tags: sql

Please help me. I've been making a report where I need to count how many got the specific rate per class and how many specific class per rate. Is my desired output even possible? Please do advise me for better solutions.
Thanks much.

=Desired Ouput

[image]

Used Query (Which generates wrong output)

```
SELECT COUNT(job_class), 
job_class, finalrate 
FROM t GROUP by job_clas
```

See my [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1027/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1027/3)

```
SELECT 
job_class, 
sum(case when finalrate like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) as AA,
sum(case when finalrate like 'B%' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
sum(case when finalrate like 'C%' then 1 else 0 end) as C
FROM t 
GROUP by job_class
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot about this.